# Set bits to one where bits of several values are all the same?

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation, bit

In order to detect where the bits of x and y are different, one can use `XOR`:

```
z = ~(x^y)
```

will set bits to one where the bits of `x` and `y` are equal.

I would like to do the same but with more than two values:

```
template <typename T0, typename... TN>
constexpr T0 same(const T0 x0, const TN... xn)
{
    // Something here
}
```

For example, for 4 values, `same(x0, x1, x2, x3)` will return a mask with bits set to one where the bits of `x0`, `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are all equal. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
same_bits = (x0 & x1 & ... & xn) | (~x1 & ~x2 & ... & ~xn))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
   template <typename T0, typename... TN>
    T0 same(const T0 x0, const TN... xn)
    {
        const int size = sizeof...(xn);
        int res[] = {xn...};
        T0 a1 = x0, a2 = ~x0;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i){
            a1 &= res[i];
            a2 &= ~res[i];
        }
        return a1 | a2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
z = (x0&x1&x2&x3) | (~x0&~x1&~x2&~x3); 
//In first bracket, get all bits that are 1, in second - all that are zero.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
~ ((x0 ^ x1) | (x0 ^ x2) | (x0 ^ x3) ... )
```

The XORs leave a zero for two facing equal bits; the ORs leave a zero when all facing bits are equal; the NOT inverts.

For `N` variables, the operation count is

`N-1` XORs, `N-2` ORs, `1` NOT (total `2N-2`).

Contrast this with other solutions that use

`2N-2` ANDs, `1` OR, `N` NOTs (total `3N-1`), or

`N-1` ANDs, `N` ORs, `1` NOT (total `2N`).

Answer (score 0):

```
and_all(x0, x1...) | ~or_all(x0, x1...)
```